# jQuery - effect of "preloading" (setinterval)?

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have the code:

```
   jQuery(img).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 0});  
        jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 1},4000);
    });
```

The code changes images opacity to 0 and then to 1. The point is it happens to all images while I want it to work for one image at the time.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you start with display:none instead of doing the animate to opacity 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's my stab at it.

```
var duration = 1000;
$('img').css('opacity', 0).each(function(i)
{
    $(this).delay(i*duration).animate({opacity: 1}, duration);
});
```

***[Demo demo demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WN3xJ/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('img').css('opacity', 0).each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 0}, i * 1000);
    jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/9J54u/4/

This will fade in one image, every 4 seconds, until all are faded in.

This works because each passes in the index of the array to your iterator function.  And you can use that index as an offset for how long before it fades in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'd want to change the first `.animate()` call to `.css('opacity', 0);`.

Comment: @Jared: I think you missed the point of the question, given that your fiddle only contains a single image.

Comment: @Matt - You're right. I was thinking it was missing something... http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9J54u/2/

Comment: Updated with @Jared's muppets :) This one actually works like you may think it would.  I didn't realize how animates timing worked.

Comment: This just makes the fade-in duration of each successive image longer, not make each fade in sequentially (with a constant effect duration).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826959/jquery-effect-of-preloading-setinterval/5827089#5827089).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I'd get each image to fade in, one after another.  When the first image finishes fading in, the second begins, and so on.

```
$(img).each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('opacity', 0);
});

doAnim(img, 0);

function doAnim(items, i) {
    if (i > items.length) return;
    $(items[i]).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        complete: function() {
            doAnim(items, i + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

[Here's a live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/ksBVy/)